# How to make a POST request in karate framework, if the content-type is multipart/formdata?

Tags: karate

I am writing a BDD(Behavior Driven Development Script) for my application using karate framework. I want to make a POST request with the content-type = multipart/formdata. While making POST request the data is not passing to the backend application.

Created a JSON file with the data in it and calling the JSON file in the .feature file.

file.json

```
{
"files[0].name": "file_1",
"files[0].type": "Audio",
"files[0].file": "classpath/folder/file.mp3",
"files[1].name": "file_2",
"files[1].type": "Video",
"files[1].file": "classpath/folder/file.3gp",
"location": "D:/files/"
}

Feature: POST call
  Background:
   # * url baseURI
  Scenario: Passing data in POST call
   Given url 'http://localhost:8080/request'
   And header Content-Type = 'multipart/formdata'
   And request read('classpath:folder/file.json')
   when method post
   Then status 200
```

Expecting the data to be saved but I don't see data passing to the backend application. Is this the correct way of passing the multipart/formdata?

Answer (score 0):

No. Please refer the docs here: https://github.com/intuit/karate#multipart-file

I am making a lot of assumptions below, please refer the docs and demo examples.

```
Given url 'http://localhost:8080/request'
And multipart file file_1 = { read: 'classpath:folder/file.mp3', filename: 'file.mp3', contentType: 'audio/mpeg' }
And multipart file file_2 = { read: 'classpath:folder/file.3gp', filename: 'file.3gp', contentType: 'video/mpeg' }
And multipart field location = 'D:/files/'
When method post
Then status 200
```